# Django check if post value exists in db

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to submit two forms with one submit button. First I want to check if form 1 already exists in the db, if id does then just post the second form using the "ticker" from first form as Foreginkey. But seem to get an error:

```
'UserTickerForm' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My code:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':

        request_form_user_ticker = UserTickerForm(request.POST)
        request_form_trade = TradesForm(request.POST)

        if request_form_user_ticker.is_valid() and request_form_trade.is_valid():
            if not User_Ticker.objects.filter(portfolio=select_portfolio, ticker=request_form_user_ticker.get('ticker')).exists():

                user_ticker_instace = request_form_user_ticker.save(commit=False)
                user_ticker_instace.portfolio = select_portfolio
                user_ticker_instace.save()

                trade_instance = request_form_trade.save(commit=False)
                trade_instance.ticker = request_form_user_ticker.get('ticker')
                trade_instance.save()

            else:
                trade_instance = request_form_trade.save(commit=False)
                trade_instance.ticker = request_form_user_ticker.get('ticker')
                trade_instance.save()
```

Does anyone know who this is happening and what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `request_form_user_ticker.get('ticker')` you should call `.get('ticker')` on cleaned data so `request_form_user_ticker.cleaned_data.get('ticker')`

Comment: @l-letovanec I'm sure i understood the solution. I Tried to do it like this: if not User_Ticker.objects.filter(portfolio=select_portfolio, ticker=request_form_user_ticker.validated_data.get('ticker')).exists():
But it gives me an error saying 'UserTickerForm' object has no attribute 'validated_data'

Comment: This got me a little further. I write YAR.OL in my ticker field in the frontend. And get the error: Cannot assign "'YAR.OL'": "Trades.ticker" must be a "User_Ticker" instance. Do you know why?